# Was Altaira's pet tiger created by Dr. Morbius's imagination?

Tags: forbidden-planet

First some background info.

- The Krell were an ancient race that were peaceful, very intelligent, and possessed of superior technology to anything humans made. The Krell lived on Altair IV until they all mysteriously died one night 200,000 years ago. The Krell had created a vast cubed-shaped machine 20 miles on each side that could read their thoughts and create whatever they wished. Such a machine would have been their greatest achievement and given them abundance for millions of years.
- Commander John J. Adams is the commanding officer of an Earth ship sent to Altair IV. His mission is to learn the fate of an earlier ship which never returned from the planet 20 years ago.
- Altaira is one of two humans on the entire planet of Altair IV. She is the only daughter of Dr. Morbius. She was born on Altair IV and grew up without contact with any other humans.
- Dr. Edward Morbius is the last survivor of the *Bellerophon*, a ship that landed on Altair IV about 20 years ago. All the crew, except him and his wife, were killed off one night by a mysterious force that vaporized the *Bellerophon*. Morbius had plugged himself into a Krell machine shortly before the *Bellerophon* tried to leave. The machine doubled his mental capacity.

> Unknown to Morbius, the machine synthesizes objects based on his thoughts. It reads his subconscious thoughts and wishes. In so doing, it created an invisible monster that destroyed his ship and killed 4 members of the crew from Adams' ship.

As Commander Adams kisses Altaira, a tiger approaches them. Altaira tells Adams that the tiger is friendly. It pounces toward them so Adams pulls out his laser gun and disintegrates it. She is surprised saying *it never did that before.*

Was the tiger created from Dr. Morbius's imagination?

Morbius believes the Krell visited Earth millions of years ago and brought back plant and animal samples. (Hence the tiger and deer and trees in the gardens around Morbius' home.)

If it was a normal tiger, it should have been just as friendly to Altaira as it always was to her.

If it was created by the Krell machine in response to Morbius subconscious mind, it would not have existed on Altair IV before he arrived.

Comment: Maybe the tiger pounced because it didn't like Commander Adams. He was a stranger to the tiger.

Comment: Or maybe Morbius' resentment of Commander Adams and the other new arrivals was reflected through the machines to the tiger. I wonder if the writers had the old *The Lady or The Tiger* story in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the novelization of the movie holds the answer. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_Planet#Novelization),

> While not stated explicitly in the film (although the basis for a deleted scene first included as an extra with the Criterion Collection's LaserDisc set and included with both the later 50th anniversary DVD and current Blu-ray releases), the novelization compared Altaira's ability to tame the tiger (until her sexual awakening with Commander Adams) to the medieval myth of a unicorn being tamable only by a virgin.
>
> The novel also includes an element never included in the film: when Dr. Ostrow dissects one of the dead Earth-type animals, he discovers that its internal structure precludes it from ever having been alive in the normal biological sense. The tiger, deer, and monkey are all conscious creations by Dr. Morbius using the great machine as companions ("pets") for his daughter and only outwardly resemble their Earth counterparts. Since the Krell's Great Machine can project matter "in any form" it has the power to create life. Thus, the Krell's self-destruction can be interpreted by the reader as a cosmic punishment for misappropriating the life-creating power of the universe. This is why Commander Adams says in his speech to Altaira "... we are, after all, not God".

The specific text from the book (running across pages 168–169) is [Dr. Ostrow is speaking]:

> “The animals.  Altaira’s animals, which—so far as she can remember—weren’t here when she was ‘a very little girl,” but then ‘just came.’”
>
> “They were experiments by Morbius.  Experiments which served the secondary purpose of providing companionship and interest for his daughter.”
>
> “My autopsy on the little titi monkey should have shown me.  It *couldn’t* have lived.  But it did.”
>
> “It lived by the power of Morbius’ mind.  Which had made it in the *outward image of his thoughts, his memories*.”

Comment: I have the novelization sitting on my desk.  Would you like me to find the relevant quote?

Comment: I am quoting Wikipedia, as I don't have the book myself. However, according to Google Books, it's on page 169 of 184.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Can you add the exact lines from the book to your answer?

Comment: @Buzz Thanks for adding the text from the story. It implies Dr. Ostrow had already deduced the animals lived by the power of Morbius's mind. How could Ostrow have known that?